# How to install exe in another system?

Tags: c#

When I install project using Microsoft installer setup  the generated executable exe file is unable to open on another system. Getting an error in Event viewer windows log application file.

> Exception Info:(Event 1026.Net Runtime error) 
>   System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32, System.String)    at
>   System.IO.FileStream.Init(System.String, System.IO.FileMode,
>   System.IO.FileAccess, Int32, Boolean, System.IO.FileShare, Int32,
>   System.IO.FileOptions, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, System.String, Boolean,
>   Boolean, Boolean)    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(System.String,
>   System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, System.IO.FileShare, Int32,
>   System.IO.FileOptions, System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)    at
>   System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(System.String, System.Text.Encoding,
>   Boolean, Int32, Boolean)    at
>   System.IO.File.InternalReadAllText(System.String,
>   System.Text.Encoding, Boolean)    at
>   **System.IO.File.ReadAllText(System.String)**

Comment: Do you have any hardcoded paths within your code? System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException does mean exactly what it is saying. There is a directory missing.

Comment: your error origins from "File.ReadAllText" you might be trying to read a file that does not exist on that OS. What file are you trying to read?

Comment: We need to see the code causing that error, as well as the error message.